# files are not saved in folder after upload using PHP

Tags: php, image, upload

I am trying to upload images to the database and save them in uploads/userimage so the images can be shown on the website. But my problem is that the image is not saved in my directory: uploads/userimage.

```
session_start(); 
include("functions/phpthumb/dbup.php");

$id = $_SESSION['werknemerid'];

// upload picture
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($_SESSION['werknemerid'] != null){  
        if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {
            // set default variables
            $image_folder = "../uploads/userimage";
            $image_tmp   = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
            $image_ext = pathinfo($_FILES["image"]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $image_name  = $_SESSION['voornaam']."".$_SESSION["tussenvoegsel"]."".$_SESSION['achternaam'].".".$image_ext;

            // move the uploaded file 
            if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $image_folder."/".$image_name)) // I think the problem is somewhere in this if statement
            {
                // load PHPThumb library
                require_once("functions/phpthumb/ThumbLib.inc.php");
                // create new thumbnail
                $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($image_folder . "/" . $image_name);
                $thumb->adaptiveResize(80,80);
                $thumb->save($image_folder . "/" . $image_name);            
            }

            $query = "UPDATE werknemer SET image = ? WHERE werknemerID = ?";
            execSQL($query, array("si", $image_name, $id), true);
            echo "<script>alert('Uw afbeelding is gewijzigd!');</script>";
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=mijnaccount' />";
        }
    }
}
// get image from database
if ($_SESSION['werknemerid'] != null){  
    $pagina_query = "SELECT image FROM werknemer WHERE werknemerID = ?";
    $pagina_result = execSQL($pagina_query, array("i", $id), false);
    $pagina_row = $pagina_result[0];
    $_SESSION["image"] = $pagina_row[image];
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong...   :(

Can someone please help?

Comment: check you upload folder path

Comment: Make sure that the "web user" has sufficient write permissions to the folder.

Comment: @Prafulla the upoad folder path is good.

Comment: ok then check for permission as Epodax suggested

Comment: @Epodax how can I see if the "web user" has sufficient write permissions t teh folder? I am using notepadd++ to connect to the ftp of the website

Comment: If you think the problem is in the if condition, confirm this for yourself by adding an else...

Comment: Erh, no idea if you can see the file permissions through notepad++, but you can with a (s)ftp or ssh program.

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` what does that show?

Comment: @Fred-ii- if I do `var_dump($_FILES);` I get: `array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(47) "68172_477387385733451_3963404340147574777_n.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phptTchbS" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(127871) } }`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Check to see also as already stated, the permissions that the folder has. It should be 755, or as a "last resort", 777.

Comment: @AlimonKarim Do I have to do that instead of something? If not where do I have to put that line?

Comment: check your upload directory permission and get the move_uploaded_file return value

Comment: someone gave you an "answer" below. you will need to take it up with them now, I am out of this loop.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if I add error reporting I get: `Notice: Use of undefined constant image - assumed 'image' in /home/wwm/domains/beveiligingsvacature.com/public_html/wijzigafbeelding.php on line 59` and the permissions of my folder are 755

Comment: post your HTML form and tell us what line 59 is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question:

Set permissions of the folder **and** subfolders to 777!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you know the $_FILES variable is set allready, but if not, make sure you have the enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag.

Turn on error reporting. You'll get a arning of the file can not be save due to permissions.

Comment: OP wouldn't see [this............](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968614/files-are-not-saved-in-folder-after-upload-using-php#comment53762440_32968614) if they didn't have it. Plus, I already told them to check for errors.

Comment: I have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my form tag and from error reporting I get: `Warning: move_uploaded_file(../uploads/userimage/MarjoleinAardewijn.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/wwm/domains/beveiligingsvacature.com/public_html/wijzigafbeelding.php on line 34 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php4cleQc' to '../uploads/userimage/MarjoleinAardewijn.jpg' in /home/wwm/domains/beveiligingsvacature.com/public_html/wijzigafbeelding.php on line 34 `

Comment: Now I get: `Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/userimage/MarjoleinAardewijn.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/wwm/domains/beveiligingsvacature.com/public_html/wijzigafbeelding.php on line 34 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpxjmfrX' to 'uploads/userimage/MarjoleinAardewijn.jpg' in /home/wwm/domains/beveiligingsvacature.com/public_html/wijzigafbeelding.php on line 34 Notice: Use of undefined constant image - assumed 'image' in /home/wwm/domains/beveiligingsvacature.com/public_html/wijzigafbeelding.php on line 56`

Comment: and the premission of my folder uploads and all the subfolders is 766

Comment: It's now working the answer to my question was: set permissions of my folder AND subfolders to 777!

Comment: Is the web user the owner of the folder?